Windows. Does it matter what order flag-switches are placed in the "dir" Command-Prompt command?
Would dir /a /b /s /o:n always work exactly the same as a different permutation of those flag-switches, such as dir /b /o:n /a /s.
Note, I include /a, without any of its Attributes, as I had an experience once where dir /b /s didn't yield all the files in a directory, for some reason, whereas dir /a /b /s did.

No. With any of the commands in command prompt, the order of the switches themselves does not matter. It may matter when you talk about switches vs filenames and of course if a switch has a sub parameter that is specified in the next parameter, then of course that next parameter must obviously come next.
For example, with shutdown, you can write /c to add a comment. The order is then always shutdown /c "My comment about the shutdown" but the /r parameter to reboot can happen before the /c and after the comment and it will work.
In commands like subst and mklink that specify both switches and filenames, the switches do come first and the order of the filenames are also important in case there are more than one. With the case of mklink being that the first specifies the link name, and the second the target that it links to, and the parameter you use always comes before both filenames.
To learn about the order of parameters, you can always run the command /? where command is subsituted for the actual command, for example: dir /?. If there is a specific order, it will tell you there. If there's no mention of a specific order, then the order doesn't matter.
So far all command prompt commands and executables seem to follow the same order:
program.exe /required_switches filenames /optional_options optional_filenames
the dir command can be run without any switches or filenames, which tells you that all switches and filenames are optional options, and as such it doesn't matter where you place them.
dir *.txt /s works just as well as dir /s *.txt

Great. Thanks for your help there, and for all that useful details also.

Feel free to mark this question as solved, so others know you nolonger need help.

Thanks for reminding me.
